# bug nested foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my code, it two  nested foreach loops:

```
$message = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM messages where pseudo ='".$Pseudo."'");

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($message)) { 
     $items[] = $data;
}

$items = array_reverse($items ,true);

foreach($items as $item) {
         echo"".$item['msg']."";
         $commentaires = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM commentaires where msg ='".$item['msg']."' and profil ='".$item['pseudo']."'");

         while($row = $commentaires->fetch_array()) { 
              $rows[] = $row;
         }

         foreach($rows as $row) {
              $abc = $row[0];$commen = $row[3];
              echo "$abc : $commen";
         }
}
```

so i've 2 entries in "messages" and 4 entries for "commentaires" 2 for the first entry of "messages" and 2 for the second. I want that :

message1
-commentaire 1
-commentaire 2

message2
-commentaire 3
-commentaire 4

and this is what i have :

message1
-commentaire 1
-commentaire 2

message2
-commentaire 1
-commentaire 2
-commentaire 3
-commentaire 4

i've search during 2 hours i don't have found a solution in mysqli :( 
(when i do

mysqli_data_seek($commentaires ,0);

that don't change anything) 
sorry for my bad English :c

Comment: Reinitialize rows variable before while loop where you fetch comments. `$rows = array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure that this:

```
while($row = $commentaires->fetch_array()){$rows[] = $row;}
```

appends rows to existing array..
which means you have to clear $rows before appending new data to it, if you want it to work as written.

I'm no PHP shark, but I do believe

```
unset($rows);
```

would do the trick

Comment: that's angry me, i've search too long, since 13H, and in 5 min i've the solution, thanks you very much ! (ha, and the array $row is not used in another code, it's weird, but cool :) )